# IBM Chatbot Assistant: Handling Multiple Entities

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have an entity called **@spare_part** and this entity has **4** values with the following example synonyms each:

**both** with synonyms **filter**, **oil level indicator**

**not_defined** with a synonym **spare part**

**only_gear** with synonyms **valve**, **seal**

**whole_gear_box** with a synonym **complete set of gearbox**

I want to be able to handle multiple entities given in the same input and address them later on, if needed. With this purpose I have coded the following in JSON editor:

```
{
"context": {
"sparepartrequest": "@spare_part.values"
},
"output": {
"generic": [
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "text": "You want an offer for the following parts: <? 
  $sparepartrequest.join(', ') ?>."
      }
    ],
    "response_type": "text",
    "selection_policy": "sequential"
  }
  ]
  }
  }
```

I have created a context variable called **sparepartrequest** as can be seen from the code lines above. For instance when the user says "I want an offer for a filter and a seal", the output of the bot is the following sentence:

**You want an offer for the following parts: both, only_gear.**

I don´t want the bot to prompt back the names of the values of the entity **@spare_part**, I rather want it to store the exact input of the user, for our case which would be **filter** and **seal**. So if the bot worked as I wanted it to, the output would look like the following:

**You want an offer for the following parts: filter, valve.**

Again, I believe that this can be handled with JSON Editor. Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two context variables. **sparepartrequest** as already done and **sparepartrequest_literals** as follows:

`"sparepartrequest_literals":"<? entities['spare_part'].![literal].join(', ') ?>"`.

Then, in your text response call it by `$sparepartrequest_literals` to print the mentioned parts or use `$sparepartrequest` to refer to the detected values.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! How do you know all these stuff ... :D One more thing. How can I refer to a specific input later on ? Let´s say the input is "I want an offer for a filter and a valve". Later on when I want to address to "valve", how will I be able to refer to it ?